# get values Date , Datetime-local in json and serialize

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
    <input type="date" id="StartDate_@item.SubjectListId" name="StartDate" class="form-control"/>
     <input type="datetime-local" id="EndDate_@item.SubjectListId" name="EndDate" class="form-control" />


    <script>

        $("#save").click(function () {

            debugger;

            var StartDate = [];
            var StartDateId = [];
            var EndDate = [];
            var EndDateId = [];

            var StartDateData = [];
            var EndDateData = [];

            $("input:date[name=StartDate]").each(function () {
                StartDateId.push($(this).attr('id'));
                StartDate.push($(this).val());
                StartDateData.push({ 'StartDate': StartDate, 'id': StartDateId })
            });

            $("input:datetime-local[name=EndDate]").each(function () {
                EndDateId.push($(this).attr('id'));
                EndDate.push($(this).val());
                EndDateData.push({ 'EndDate': EndDate, 'id': EndDateId })
            });



         var JsonStartdate = JSON.stringify(StartDateData)
         var JsonEndDate = JSON.stringify(EndDateData)
   $.ajax({
 // AJAX CODE 
),
});
</script>
```

how i can take the values of type date and datetime-local with same name and different id in script also how to serialize and pass to controller like input:text[name=txtname]

Comment: I removed the Java tag, because there is no relation to it

Comment: thank you i was looking how to remove it